# Which Ubuntu release with 5.4 kernel should I use for NVIDIA 340 legacy drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm not experienced Linux user. I merely need it to compose Docker images for my projects and run integration tests with Testcontainers on IntelliJ IDEA. For now, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 next to Windows 10 and switch-boot between them when needed. The only problem is that my legacy NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT card, which still works perfectly on Windows 10, is completely useless on Ubuntu 22.04 (well, at least not with its current 5.19 kernel). NVIDIA officials say 340.108 drivers are supported only for Linux kernels up to Linux 5.4.

So, I'm wondering, is there any archive repository or something like that from where I can get a descent Desktop Ubuntu release running on that 5.4 kernel as the default, so that I can replace Ubuntu 22.04 with it? Can you recommend which version of Ubuntu with 5.4 kernel should I use for that reason?

P.S.
I also tried to install NVIDIA 340.108 patched drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 (from ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy and the like) - but with no success.

Comment: 20.04 was released with the 5.4 kernel. You can get it from [here](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack also uses the 5.4 kernel, however Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches its EOSS next month so I'd avoid installs with it.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS only uses the GA kernel stack (5.4) if you install with media that defaults to it (*there are many older ISOs that did this*), OR change to install GA kernel stack (*if using an ISO that defaults to HWE which all Ubuntu Desktop ISOs do, as do flavors with 20.04.2 or later media*)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 (*bionic*) currently uses `linux-generic | 4.15.0.208.191         | bionic-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` and Ubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) currently uses `linux-generic | 5.4.0.146.144          | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 currently has kernel 5.4.0-146-generic. According to this page https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle you should download the 18.04.5 point release to start with the 5.4 kernel, which can be done here: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/

The downside is that it's only supported for one more month.

You can get longer support by signing up for Ubuntu Pro, but after the official support period ends in a month, it will be off-topic here.

Comment: For those, who are still curious, there is [a couple of fixes](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2485542&p=14138357#post14138357) how to get nvidia-340 drivers fully operational on later Ubuntu LTS releases (which are at the time of writing - 20.04 and 22.04).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the **HWE** kernel stack also uses the 5.4 kernel, however Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches its **EOSS** next month so I'd avoid installs with it.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS only using the **GA** kernel stack (5.4) if you install with media that defaults to it (*there are many older ISOs that did this*), OR change to install **GA** kernel stack (*if using an ISO that defaults to HWE which all Ubuntu Desktop ISOs do, as do flavors with 20.04.2 or later media*)

Ubuntu 18.04 (*bionic*) currently (using HWE) uses

`linux-generic-hwe-18.04 | 5.4.0.146.163~18.04.117 | bionic-security | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`

and Ubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) currently (using GA) uses

`linux-generic | 5.4.0.146.144          | focal-security   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x`